# How to split a Kotlin flow into 2 flows?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to learn coroutines and i am still having some basic issues. 
I have a flow that emits a sequence of items and i want to split the stream into 2 flows. This is how i would write it in RxJava:

```
    val list = Flowable.just(1..6).share()
    val even = list.filter { it % 2 == 0 }.subscribe { println(it) } // 2, 4, 6
    val odd = list.filter { it % 2 == 1 }.subscribe { println(it) } // 1, 3, 5
```

How can i replicate this with Kotlin coroutine flows ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with `.filter {}.forEach {}`?

Comment: If you are trying to learn coroutines forget about `Flow`s for the moments. Learn coroutines and then jump to flows

Answer (score 4):

A family of [sharing operators](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1261) (as well as [a hot `SharedFlow`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2034)) are on their way to simplify the kind of workflow you're looking for (using Kotlin Flows).

In the meantime, it's true that flows are cold in nature (and thus you cannot really *share* them as-is), but they can nevertheless share a hot source to achieve what you need. I provided details on how to do this [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61855999/1540818).

In short, the end result looks like this:

```kotlin
val original: Flow<String> = flowOf("aap", "noot", "mies", "wim", "zus","jet","weide","does")

// create an implicit hot BroadcastChannel, shared between collectors
// so that they each get all elements (which are each produced only once)
val sharedFlow = original.broadcastIn(scope).asFlow()

// create derived cold flows, which will subscribe (on collect) to the
// same hot source (BroadcastChannel)
val flow1 = sharedFlow.filter { it.length == 4 }
val flow2 = sharedFlow.filter { it.length == 3 }.map { it.toUppercase() }

flow1.collect { it -> println("Four letter: ${it}") }
flow2.collect { it -> println("Three letter: ${it}") }
```

(This is soon to be replaced by a `SharedFlow`.)

Answer (score 2):

What you did with Rx is somewhat impossible with *Kotlin flows*, since in your example `share()` will create a **hot observable** and flows in Kotlin are by nature **cold**.

You could use a `Channel` instead since they represent **hot streams** in Kotlin.

I'd read this blog-post about [Cold flows, hot channels](https://medium.com/@elizarov/cold-flows-hot-channels-d74769805f9) from **Roman Elizarov**.

Answer (score 0):

just "played around" with a comparable "challenge".

I wanted to "split" the result Flow of (possibly many) producers in a round-robin manner to multiple asynchronous consumers.

Achieving that:

- the producer produces a flow "in the background"
- one / many consumers consume chunks of the producers outcome in a round-robin fashion
  (also "in the background")
- while all of this happens, you can continue to "do something" until all data is produced AND consumed

To achieve the above I used `MutableSharedFlow` and after the producer (and consumers) finished "their" flows finally had to be canceled/finished.

I doubt that my result is in any way optimal or even a "good" solution, but as I have spend a "significant" time on it (learning) I thought I might share it here as well:

```kotlin
package scratch

import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import okio.*
import kotlin.random.Random

data class Packet(val nr: Int, val cmd: String, val line: String, val isFinal: Boolean = false)
class TerminatedException(message: String, cause: Throwable? = null) : Exception(message, cause)

/** possible multiple producers sending to one MutableSharedFlow</br>
 *  multiple consumers fed round-robin from the one SharedFlow of all producers */
fun main(@Suppress("UNUSED_PARAMETER") args: Array<String>) {
    println("===============================")
    println("====   multipleConsumers() ====")
    println("===============================")
    showcaseMultipleConsumers()

    println("\nmompl...\n")
    Thread.sleep(2000L)

    println("===============================")
    println("=====   singleConsumer() ======")
    println("===============================")
    showcaseSingleConsumer()

    println("main ended.")
}

private fun showcaseMultipleConsumers() {
    runBlocking {

        // launch producer with SharedFlow to emit to
        val producerFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Packet>()
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            producer(name = "producer", cmd = "/Users/hoffi/gitRepos/scratch/scratch/some.sh", producerFlow)
        }

        // launch concurrent consumers with each its own SharedFlow
        val consumerCount = 3
        val mapOfFlows = mutableMapOf<Int, MutableSharedFlow<Packet>>()
        for (i in 1..consumerCount) {
            mapOfFlows[i - 1] = MutableSharedFlow()
            launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                consume(i.toString(), mapOfFlows[i - 1]!!)
            }
        }
        println("finished launching $consumerCount consumers.")

        // round-robin emit from the producerFlow to the existing MutableSharedFlows
        var i = 0
        try {
            producerFlow.buffer().collect() { packet ->
                if (packet.isFinal) {
                    println("producer: final packet received"); throw TerminatedException("'producer' terminated")
                }
                mapOfFlows[i++ % consumerCount]!!.emit(packet)
            }
        } catch (e: TerminatedException) {
            println(e.message)
        }

        println("round-robbin load-balancing finished.")

        // finally send terminal packet to all consumer's MutableSharedFlows
        for (flow in mapOfFlows.values) {
            flow.emit(Packet(-1, "final", "final", true))
        }

        // might do something here _after_ the process has finished and its output is load-balanced to consumers
        // but consuming of process output has not finished yet.

        println("end of runBlocking ...")
    }
}

/** coroutine consuming from given Flow (which is a MutableSharedFlow!) */
suspend fun consume(name: String, flow: Flow<Packet>) {
    try {
        flow.buffer().collect { packet ->
            if (packet.isFinal)  { println("$name: final packet received") ; throw TerminatedException("'$name' terminated") }
            println("%5d in c%s: %s".format(packet.nr, name, packet.line))
            delay(Random.nextLong(50L, 550L))
        }
    } catch(e: TerminatedException) {
        println("consumer: ${e.message}")
    }
}

/** coroutine emitting to given producer's MutableSharedFlow */
suspend fun producer(name: String, cmd: String, producerFlow: MutableSharedFlow<Packet>) {
    val process = ProcessBuilder("\\s".toRegex().split(cmd))
        .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
        .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
        .redirectErrorStream(true)
        .start() // non-blocking asynchronous start process in the background

    val inputBuffer = process.inputStream.source().buffer()
    var i = 0
    while (true) {
        val line = inputBuffer.readUtf8Line() ?: break
        producerFlow.emit(Packet(++i, cmd, line))
    }

    producerFlow.emit(Packet(-1, "final", "final", true))
    println("producer function ended")
}

// =====================================================================================================================
// =====================================================================================================================
// =====================================================================================================================

private fun showcaseSingleConsumer() {
    runBlocking {

        val flow: Flow<Packet> = singleProducer(name = "producer", cmd = "/Users/hoffi/gitRepos/scratch/scratch/some.sh")
        launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            singleConsumer(name = "consumer", flow)
        }

        // do something here, while the process is executed
        // and the consumer is consuming the process's output

        println("end of runBlocking ...")

    }
}

/** no suspend needed as a flow { ... } implicitly "runs in a coroutine" */
fun singleProducer(name: String, cmd: String) = flow {
    val process = ProcessBuilder("\\s".toRegex().split(cmd))
        .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
        .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
        .redirectErrorStream(true)
        .start() // non-blocking asynchronous start process in the background

    val inputBuffer = process.inputStream.source().buffer()
    var i = 0
    while (true) {
        val line = inputBuffer.readUtf8Line() ?: break
        emit(Packet(++i, cmd, line))
    }

    println("producer function ended")
}

suspend fun singleConsumer(name: String, flow: Flow<Packet>) {
    flow.buffer().collect { packet ->
        println("%5d in c%s: %s".format(packet.nr, name, packet.line))
        delay(Random.nextLong(30L, 150L))
    }
}
```

`some.sh` shellscript used as "data source":

```bash
#!/bin/bash
 # some.sh
echo "first line"
echo -e "second line\nand third line"
echo -n "fourth line without newline"
sleep 2
echo
echo -e "fifth line after sleep\nand sixth line"
echo -e "some stderr\nand stderr has two lines" >&2
for i in {1..25}; do
  echo "and loop line $i"
done
echo -n "last line"
```