# How do you split a 'hot' stream of events from a callback in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm processing a hot stream of events, arriving by callback. 'Downstream' I'd like to split it into multiple streams, and process them.The events all arrive sequentially from a single thread (which I don't control, so I don't think I can use co routines here)
What is the right structure to use here?

I can create a Flow pretty easily, using callbackFlow and sendBlocking, but the semantics don't seem to line up, as the Flow isn't cold.
What is the best way to split a flow into multiple downstream flows (depending on the contents of events). Or should I use channels? It matches the 'hotness' of my source, but the whole polling downstream seems off (in this basically synchronoussituation), and a lot of the methods seem deprecated in favor of Flow.

I *can* do all this by just using 'callbacks all the way' but that creates a lot tighter coupling than I'd like. Any ideas?

Edit:

I ended up with this, seems to work:

```kotlin
    fun testFlow() {
        runBlocking {
            val original = flowOf("aap", "noot", "mies", "wim", "zus","jet","weide","does")
            val broadcast = original.broadcastIn(this)
            val flow1 = broadcast.openSubscription().receiveAsFlow().filter { it.length == 4 }
            val flow2 = broadcast.openSubscription().receiveAsFlow().filter { it.length == 3 }
            flow1.collect { it -> println("Four letter: ${it}") }
            flow2.collect { it -> println("Three letter: ${it}") }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using `receiveAsFlow()` doesn't cancel the subscription channel automatically, you should prefer `consumeAsFlow()` in this case. That being said, `openSubscription().consumeAsFlow()` creates 2 hot flows immediately, while using `asFlow()` actually keeps the "child flows" cold, and only creates subscriptions when they are `collect`-ed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Short answer

There will soon be a hot [`SharedFlow`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2034) for this use case, but in the meantime you can use a `BroadcastChannel` under the cover.

You can start with [`callbackFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html) to create a cold flow from a callback based API (see Roman Elizarov's [post about it](https://medium.com/@elizarov/callbacks-and-kotlin-flows-2b53aa2525cf)).
Then use the following to make it hot and share it:

```
val original: Flow<String> = TODO("get original flow")

// create an implicit hot BroadcastChannel, shared between collectors
val sharedFlow = original.broadcastIn(scope).asFlow()

// create derived cold flows, which will subscribe (on collect) to the
// same hot source (BroadcastChannel)
val flow1 = sharedFlow.filter { it.length == 4 }
val flow2 = sharedFlow.filter { it.length == 3 }.map { it.toUppercase() }

flow1.collect { it -> println("Four letter: ${it}") }
flow2.collect { it -> println("Three letter: ${it}") }
```

### Making a flow hot (the current way)

First to clarify, even if `Flow`s are mostly cold for now, there is already a hot `StateFlow`, and there will soon be a convenient [`share` operator](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1261) and a hot [`SharedFlow`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2034) to simplify this kind of use case.

While we wait for this, if you initially have a cold `Flow`, you currently have to first create a hot channel (and a coroutine to send elements to it) from which we derive flows sharing the hot source. This can easily be done in one of these ways:

- [`Flow.produceIn(scope)`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/produce-in.html) launches a coroutine in the given scope and gives you a `ReceiveChannel` (useful for fan-out, see below)
- [`Flow.broadcastIn(scope)`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/broadcast-in.html) launches a coroutine in the given scope and gives you a `BroadcastChannel` (useful for actual sharing, see below)

Once you have a hot channel, you can convert it into a flow and get different behaviours:

- [`ReceiveChannel.consumeAsFlow()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/consume-as-flow.html) creates a `Flow` from a hot source, but it can only be `collect`-ed by a single collector (throws otherwise)
- [`ReceiveChannel.receiveAsFlow()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/receive-as-flow.html) creates a multi-collector `Flow`, but it behaves in a fan-out fashion (each element form the source channel only goes to one consumer)
- [`BroadcastChannel.asFlow()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/as-flow.html) creates a multi-collector `Flow` where each collector gets all elements (which is effectively sharing). Calling `collect` creates a new subscription on the `BroadcastChannel`, and handles cancellation properly.

### "Latest state" semantics with `StateFlow`

This is not your use case, but sometimes you may not want necessarily all values in a flow, but rather the latest current state and state updates.

This used to be done via a `ConflatedBroadcastChannel`, but you can now use a [`StateFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/index.html) to represent this (since coroutines 1.3.6):

- on the producer side, set the value of a `MutableStateFlow`
- on the consumer side, each collector will get the current state when they start, and then get a new state value each time it is different from the previous one (based on `equal`ity).

Comment: I've cobbled together an example, I think I'm good, thanks man.

Comment: @FrankLee What I was describing is somewhat equivalent to what you're doing. I'm just making use of `asFlow()` to remove the explicit channel subscriptions, because it handles automatically the underlying channel cancellations. Please see the example code I provided based on your snippet.